# Issue in importing AKS cluster on Paralus

Tags: rbac, kubernetes-rbac

I am running Paralus using ztka helm chart.

something like: helm install paralus -f myvalues.yaml -n paralus paralus/ztka

All the services are working fine, even after a struggle in migrate-admindb step.

While I am trying to import my aks cluster in the paralus dasboard after generating bootstrap.yaml. I am getting below error:

`{"level":"error","ts":"2023-01-25T14:48:10.532Z","caller":"agent/agent.go:354","msg":"Relay Agent::failed to register relay agent error: Post \"https://console.paralus.dev:443/v2/sentry/bootstrap/template%2Fcebd1j8cmdg1vouhohrg/register\": dial tcp: lookup console.paralus.dev on 10.0.0.10:53: no such host  ","stacktrace":"github.com/paralus/relay/pkg/agent.registerRelayAgent\n\t/build/pkg/agent/agent.go:354\ngithub.com/paralus/relay/pkg/agent.handleRelayNetworks\n\t/build/pkg/agent/agent.go:560"}`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2siM.png)

I can see that it is routing on https://console.paralus.dev:443 while my Paralus-dasboard is having a different domain. I tried modifying bootstrap.yaml and services but no luck.

Please help in resolving this.

Thank you !!!

I am doing POC on RBAC control for kubernetes cluster using Paralus